# How to install PCL on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, point-cloud-library

I am new in Point Cloud Library and I would like to know how can I install it on my computer. I have already installed PCL 1.6.0 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 but I can't manage to use PCL. I understand that I am supposed to set references at some point but I am totally clueless as how and when I should do it.

I have been trying to follow the instructions at http://unanancyowen.com/?p=1255&lang=en but when I get to :

Set the environment variable for PCL and 3rdParty.
Variable Name   Variable Value
PCL_ROOT    C:\Program Files\PCL 1.7.2(or C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.7.2)
Path    ;%PCL_ROOT%\bin
;%PCL_ROOT%\3rdParty\FLANN\bin
;%PCL_ROOT%\3rdParty\VTK\bin

I am totally lost...
I have never used neither Visual Studio nor PCL before.

I am using windows7 64bits

If you could hint me in the right direction or direct me to a tutorial that I could understand, that would be very helpfull !!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your PCL version is not right...I use PCL 1.7.2 and VS2012 on Win8.1, and it's the same on win7.
Look at this [tutorial](http://www.pclcn.org/bbs/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=1195&extra=page%3D1)(It's in chinese and you can use google translate, I follow it and succeed to run PCL1.7.2 on my VS2012):

Answer (score 0):

I used the website you mentioned to install pcl in my computer. And it works just fine. And quite detailed compared to other tutorials. From your question, I understand that you have trouble adding the path to the environment variables. If thats not what you are having trouble with, let me know.

The environment variable helps the visual studio compiler to find the paths to PCL libraries during run time. So, after installing PCL, we need to tell the computer where we have installed pcl and pcl bin files and the supporting 3rd party libraries. You do that by editing the path.

As for how to set the environment variable, go through this tutorial: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm